# Snakemake: Error when trying to run a rule for multiple directories and files

Tags: snakemake

I create a dictionary in python and save the path to the directories (that I want the software to run on) as the keys and the corresponding values are a list of the expected output for each directory. Right now I have a structure like this:

```
sampleDict = {'/path_to_directory1': ["sample1","sample2","sample3"], 
              '/path_to_directory2': ["sample1","sample2"], 
              '/path_to_directory3': ["sample1","sample2","sample3"]}

# sampleDict looks pretty much like this
# key is a path to the directory that I want the rule to be executed on and the corresponding value sampleDict[key] is an array e.g. ["a","b","c"]

def input():
    input=[]
    for key in dirSampleDict:
            input.extend(expand('{dir}/{sample}*.foo', dir = key, sample=dirSampleDict[key]))
    return input




rule all:
    input:
        input()


# example should run some software on different directories for each set of directories and their expected output samples
rule example:
      input:
          # the path to each set of samples should be the wildcard
          dir = lambda wildcards: expand("{dir}", dir=dirSampleDict.keys())
      params:
       # some params
      output:
          expand('{dir}/{sample}*.foo', dir = key, sample=dirSampleDict[key])
      log:
          log = '{dir}/{sample}.log'
      run:
        cmd = "software {dir}"
        shell(cmd)
```

Doing this I receive the following error:

> No values given for wildcard 'dir

Edit: Maybe it was not so clear what I actually want to do so I filled in some data.

I also tried using the wildcards I set up in rule all as follows:

```
sampleDict = {'/path_to_directory1': ["sample1","sample2","sample3"], 
              '/path_to_directory2': ["sample1","sample2"], 
              '/path_to_directory3': ["sample1","sample2","sample3"]}

# sampleDict looks pretty much like this
# key is a path to the directory that I want the rule to be executed on and the corresponding value sampleDict[key] is an array e.g. ["a","b","c"]

def input():
    input=[]
    for key in dirSampleDict:
            input.extend(expand('{dir}/{sample}*.foo', dir = key, sample=dirSampleDict[key]))
    return input




rule all:
    input:
        input()


# example should run some software on different directories for each set of directories and their expected output samples
rule example:
      input:
          # the path to each set of samples should be the wildcard
          dir = "{{dir}}"
      params:
       # some params
      output:
          '{dir}/{sample}*.foo'
      log:
          log = '{dir}/{sample}.log'
      run:
        cmd = "software {dir}"
        shell(cmd)
```

Doing this I receive the following error:

> Not all output, log and benchmark files of rule example contain the
> same wildcards. This is crucial though, in order to avoid that two or
> more jobs write to the same file.

I'm pretty sure the second part is more likely what I actually want to do, since expand() as output would only run the rule once but I need to run it for every key value pair in the dictonary.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, what do you expect from the asterisk in the output?

```py
    output:
        '{dir}/{sample}*.foo'
```

The output has to be a list of valid filenames that can be formed with substitution of each wildcard with some string.

Next problem is that you are using the `"{dir}"` in the `run:` section. There is no variable `dir` defined in the script used for run. If you want to use the wildcard, you need to address it using `wildcards.dir`. However the `run:` can be substituted with a `shell:` section:

```py
    shell:
        "software {wildcards.dir}"
```

Regarding your first script: there is no `dir` wildcard defined (actually there are no wildcards at all):

```py
    output:
        expand('{dir}/{sample}*.foo', dir = key, sample=dirSampleDict[key])
```

Both `{dir}` and `{sample}` are the variables in the context of `expand` function, and they are fully substituted with the named parameters.

Now the second script. What did you mean by this input?

```py
    input:
        dir = "{{dir}}"
```

Here the `"{{dir}}"` is not a wildcard, but a reference to a global variable (you haven't provided the rest of your script, so I cannot judge whether it is defined or not). Moreover, what's the need in the input? You never use the `{input}` variable at all, and there is no dependencies that are needed to connect the `rule example` with any other rule to produce the input for `rule example`.